# No metrics in CloudWatch for SNS topics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

I have a few SNS topics in my aws account in the same region (us-west-2), somehow, I can see Topic Metrics for a couple of them, but not the rest.

I followed [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-monitoring-using-cloudwatch.html#view-cloudwatch-metrics), but a few of my SNS topics just don't show up here, and I even tried search, nothing shows up:
[image]

I compared side by side for the few SNS topics that do have metrics that show up on CloudWatch and those that don't, I don't see any configuration differences.

My understanding is that these monitoring would come out of the box, i.e. when you create a standard SNS topic, AWS CloudWatch will automatically monitor and aggregate metrics and display on CloudWatch, isn't it? How can I find these metrics for a few of my SNS topics.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the T at the end a typing error? `RDSEventMonitorT` instead of `RDSEventMonitor`?

Comment: Nope, it's just the full name of this topic, I knew CloudWatch doesn't support prefix search here, so copied the full name, I know the naming itself is a bit odd, agreed.